# What is causing my C# WASM function to run slowly?

Tags: javascript, c#, webassembly

I was playing around with csharp wasm features in dotnet 7, and was seeing a huge speed difference where csharp was extremely slow compared to JavaScript. I was just concatenating a bunch of numbers.

In csharp, it took a over 60 seconds to concatenate 100k numbers together. Whereas in JavaScript, to do the same thing took ~20ms.

[image: Results]

What caused this?

The C# code

```cs
public partial class MyClass
{
  [JSExport]
  internal static string CountTo(int number)
  {
    var text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
      text += $"{i}";
    }
    return text;
  }
}
```

The JavaScript

```js
import { dotnet } from './dotnet.js';
const { getAssemblyExports, getConfig } = await dotnet.create();

const count = 100000;

const config = getConfig();
const exports = await getAssemblyExports(config.mainAssemblyName);

// Test the C# WASM function
console.time('csharp');
exports.MyClass.CountTo(count);
console.timeEnd('csharp');

function countTo(number) {
    var text = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        text += `${i}`;
    }
    return text;
}

// Test the JavaScript function
console.time('js');
countTo(count);
console.timeEnd('js');
```

I was to believe that WASM was supposed to be faster aka native speeds...

Comment: Can you repeat the test but using `StringBuilder` instead of `string` in c#? That would be the canonical way of implementing this in C#

Comment: Hmmm... That really does decrease the time (still slower than JS though, but I assume the time includes startup time).

Comment: After testing 10M items: `csharp: 17934.3388671875 ms` `js: 2054.655029296875 ms` still big differences.

Comment: If you compare the time between 10million items and 20million items, do both times double or is there maybe some constant offset of using WebASM?

Comment: 20M: `csharp: 37403.525146484375 ms` `js: 3840.5419921875 ms`

Comment: Hm, interesting. Indeed looks like the C# version is slower. And it is not because of some constant startup-delay.

Comment: Adding `<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
        <TrimMode>full</TrimMode>
        <RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>` to my config made the csharp go to `csharp: 3145.541748046875 ms`

Comment: Does running the csharp function the second time in a row also takes so long?

Comment: When running twice with C# and once with JS it looks like this:

`csharp: 3091.125 ms`
`csharp2: 2903.032958984375 ms`
`js: 3426.673095703125 ms`

Comment: Converting c# code to use _StringBuilder_ and using all mentioned _csproj_ options left me at 300ms difference on average between js and c#. Interesting that here https://betterprogramming.pub/how-fast-is-webassembly-versus-javascript-bc0eca058a54 the same innate difference mentioned.